# Selenium Web Driver : Kendo UI Drop down value cant be selected while running the code to test,

Tags: selenium-webdriver, kendo-ui

Selenium Web Driver: I really looking for something that can help me to select value from kendo UI , I've tried it many times using diff kinda find elements techniques. But it will only work when I hover the mouse over the drop down list.

Comment: can you paste sample url link where we can replicate your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Write a method that moves the mouse to the hover location before you look for the element. Something like

```
public void ClickElementAfterHover(IWebElement hoverElement, IWebElement elementToClick)
{
   Actions action = new Actions(Driver);
   action.MoveToElement(hoverElement);
   elementToClick.Click()
}
```